# Joi: How to use default values with xor?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, schema, joi

I need to do a validation somewhat *like* xor, but Joi treats null values as truthy. The only thing that is falsey in their xor is undefined / missing keys, so something like this won't work:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string().empty('').default(null),
  b: Joi.string().empty('').default(null),
}).xor('a', 'b')
```

The reason I need this is I need to grab the returned value and I need all keys to be present, and set to null rather than leaving them undefined / missing.

```
// this doesn't validate since 'b' defaults to null before the .xor() check
const { error, value } = schema.validate({ a: 'test' });
```

I'm having a hard time coming up with a way to do this with Joi. I can easily add the key back with some custom handler or something, but if there is a way to do this with Joi, that would be much cleaner!

Comment: Did you try [Schema.invalid()](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.2#anyinvalidvalues---aliases-disallow-not) with `undefined` as a param?

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps? I am trying to allow null values, but still do xor analysis which treats the null values as "false".